# How to validade a XML file with xsd file using just javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I have a xml file and I want to validate from xsd file using javascript.
I found some node libraries in node, but I need process it using whit only js

Comment: I'm not aware of an XSD validator that works in JS.